# If MIN value occurs more than once with returned values

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Problem:** I want to return Golfer name if they have the lowest score on a hole. If the lowest score (MIN) appears more than once, return "N/A".

| Golfer | Score |
| --- | --- |
| John | 3 |
| mark | 4 |
| Mike | 6 |
| Frank | 5 |

I'm assuming it's an `IF` statement with `MIN` and `CountIF` but I can't seem to get them in the right combination.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use COUNTIFS to see if more than one and if not then use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B:B,MIN(B:B))>1,"N/A",INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MIN(B:B),B:B,0)))
```

[image]